# How to get enclosing area of a text drawn on an HDC in c++?

Tags: c++, windows, rendering, gdi

I am trying to figure out the ending point of a text drawn on an HDC. For this I am using  [DrawTextEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which is giving me an enclosing rectangle. Is there any way I can get the location where last character of text is drawn ? For example :-

[image: Text with enclosing rectangl]
In case of above image I am trying to get the location of "." (which is the last character). Is there any mechanism by which I can do that ?